# How to Add a New ENUM Values to Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, enums

i want to add new enum values called "pending" to existing table so the enum will be ['paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free']

[the table on phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiSNR.jpg)

so i try to define it on migration and i think it would automatically update when i run "php artisan migrate" but there is no migrate

[migration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ovv.jpg)

So can you help me how to add the new values "pending"?

Comment: *i want to add new enum values called "pending" to existing table so the enum will be ['paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free']* Such change needs in METHOD=COPY. Why you do not store the existing values ordering and do not add additional value to the end of values list? *but there is no migrate* What does this means? you create the migration file but it dissappears? you start it but it fails with some error? it does not alter the structure w/o error? something else?

Comment: Please post your source code/error and avoid posting images. Refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Also why does your migration file have Schema create, shouldn't you be using Alter Table instead since you are trying to modify an existing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a New Migration:
Run the following Artisan command to create a new migration file:

```
php artisan make:migration add_pending_to_status_enum_in_table_name --table=your_table_name
```

Here’s an example of what the up and down methods in your migration file might look like:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AddPendingToStatusEnumInTableName extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE your_table_name MODIFY COLUMN your_enum_column ENUM('paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free')");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE your_table_name MODIFY COLUMN your_enum_column ENUM('paid', 'unpaid', 'free')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You migration file should be like this

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('payment_spps', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->enum('January', ['paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free',])->default('unpaid')->change();
        // other columns ...
    });
}
```

If it dose not work , you can try this

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('payment_spps', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE payment_spps MODIFY COLUMN `January` ENUM('paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free')");
    });
}
```

if you want to set default value with it

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('payment_spps', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE payment_spps MODIFY COLUMN `January` ENUM('paid', 'unpaid', 'pending', 'free') default('unpaid') ");
    });
}
```